# Dynamic DLL loading in IIS7 fails

Tags: c#, iis, dll, iis-7, dllimport

We have two web services Running on separate application pools in IIS7. The web services are identical, what differs is that one connects to the test Database and the other to the live database.

The Web services require a DLL which was written in Delphi to churn out some of the business logic required by the system, which we are loading using Dynamic DLL Loading like so:

```
public static class DynamicLinking
    {
        private static int libHandle;
        private static string dllName;

        public static void init(String pDllName)
        {
            dllName = pDllName;
            libHandle = LoadLibrary(pDllName);
        }

        public static void fini()
        {
            FreeLibrary(libHandle);
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibrary")]
        static extern int LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpLibFileName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetProcAddress")]
        static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(int hModule, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpProcName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeLibrary")]
        static extern bool FreeLibrary(int hModule);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        delegate bool QryFunction(string domainString, string qryString,
                                     int outputStringBufferSize, ref string outputStringBuffer);
        public static void ExecuteDLLFunction(string pfunctionName, int bufferSize,
                                               string pDomain, string inputXMLString,
                                                out string outputString)
        {

            if (libHandle == 0)
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not load library \"{0}\"", dllName));

            var delphiFunctionAddress = GetProcAddress(libHandle, pfunctionName);
            if (delphiFunctionAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Can't find function \"{0}\" in library \"{1}\"", pfunctionName, dllName));

            var queryFunction = (QryFunction)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(delphiFunctionAddress, typeof(QryFunction));

            var outputStringBuffer = new String('\x00', bufferSize);
            var errorMsgBuffer = new String('\x00', bufferSize);

            if (!queryFunction(pDomain, inputXMLString,
                                bufferSize, ref outputStringBuffer))
                throw new Exception(errorMsgBuffer);

            outputString = outputStringBuffer;   

        }
    }
```

Now the problem lies here: when we start the web the websites, which ever site gets started last will fail to load the dll, while the first one to load will run fine.

//edit---------------------------------
What's strange is that when the same DLL is copied in each website this issue arises however, if we link both sites to the same DLL, everything works fine

Any insight on this?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the DLL. Hard to tell. You need to add some diagnostics and find out which call fails (is it `LoadLibrary`) and if so what the error code is. You'll need `SetLastError = true` on your p/invokes.

Comment: Any chance that the DLL is using a lockable resource (file on disk for logging, etc.)? You really need an error message to be able to diagnose this.

Answer (score 0):

You should out each site in a separate App Pool, so that IIS will run each one in a its own process.